# User with 1 rep approved edit?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, suggested-edits

So I just suggested an edit, which got approved by a user with 1 rep.

How can he approve a suggested edit with 1 rep, while I cannot with 486 rep?

Comment: Was the post that you suggested an edit to that user's post ?  1 rep users still have ability to comment on their own posts and answers , and likely approve edits on their own posts

Comment: Bingo. Didn't even think of that!

Comment: Note that "colour" is not an error.

Comment: @kos Okay, it's correct in the U.K... but that part about adding Xubuntu was helpful since I only found that by looking at the tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was the original poster of the question who approved my edit. The original poster, even with 1 rep, can still approve suggestions to their own questions.